# Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric when running together

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the arithmetic overflow error. When I run them one at a time it works fine but when they both run I get the error. UNITCNT1 is data type 'text' unfortunately.  Any ideas on why they work separate but not together? Using SQL Server. Thanks.

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
       WHEN CAST(UNITCNT1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = .00 
          THEN 'ALL AGES' 
          ELSE '' 
    END AS AGE_CAT,
    CASE 
       WHEN CAST(UNITCNT1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) >= 18.00 
          THEN 'ADULT' 
          ELSE '' 
    END AS AGE_CAT1
FROM 
    UNITS
```

Answer (score 0):

this work correctly  , because of your equal operator and you can change your query like this :

```
DECLARE @UNITS TABLE
    (
      UNITCNT1 VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    insert into @UNITS values(12)

    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CAST(UNITCNT1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) = '.00' THEN 'ALL AGES' ELSE '' END AS AGE_CAT 
    ,CASE WHEN CAST(UNITCNT1 AS VARCHAR(MAX)) >= 18.00 THEN 'ADULT' ELSE '' END AS AGE_CAT1
    FROM @UNITS
```

i think its better use decimal format for numeric column , like this:

```
    DECLARE @UNITS TABLE
    (
      UNITCNT1 VARCHAR(MAX) -- or decimal type i dont know your schema
    )

    insert into @UNITS values(12)

    SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CAST(UNITCNT1 AS decimal) = .00 THEN 'ALL AGES' ELSE '' END AS AGE_CAT 
    ,CASE WHEN CAST(UNITCNT1 AS decimal) >= 18.00 THEN 'ADULT' ELSE '' END AS AGE_CAT1
    FROM @UNITS
```